# Но отрабатывает триггер, запрещающий вставку

Tags: postgresql

У меня есть вот такой вот триггер

```
CREATE  TRIGGER check_insertion_to_pushes_table
BEFORE INSERT ON "Pushes"
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_insert_failed_push();

CREATE or replace FUNCTION trg_insert_failed_push()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(
            SELECT *
            FROM "Pushes"
            where "Sent" = NEW."Sent"
              and "Sent" = false
              and "CustomerId" = NEW."CustomerId"
              and "PushTemplateId" = NEW."PushTemplateId"
        )
    THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Такая запись уже есть';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

И вот такая вот таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно пропускать запись в таблицу `Pushes` если уже есть строка, где `CustomerId` = CustomerId вставляемой строки и `PushTemplateId` = PushTemplateId вставляемой строки и `Sent` = false. При этом, во вставляемой строке тоже `Sent` = false. Если во вставляемой строке `Sent` = true то вставить запись.
Я использую Entity Framework ORM, поэтому не могу контролировать, как именно выглядит запрос на вставку. Но, скорее всего, это инсерт со многими значениями. Соответственно для меня нежелательное поведение - если данный триггер будет "убивать" всю транзакцию. Мне нужно, чтоб среди всех вставляемых строк, он не дал вставить те, которые подходят под его условия.

Сейчас триггер обрубает всю транзакцию. А мне нужно, чтобы он молча пропустил те строки, которые не подходят.

Answer (score 1):

Отлично, я справился!

Вот правильный код триггера:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_insertion_to_pushes_table
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON "Pushes"
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_insert_failed_push();

CREATE or replace FUNCTION trg_insert_failed_push()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(
            SELECT *
            FROM "Pushes"
            where "Sent" = NEW."Sent"
              and "Sent" = false
              and "CustomerId" = NEW."CustomerId"
              and "PushTemplateId" = NEW."PushTemplateId"
        )
    THEN
       RETURN NULL; /* ТУТ НАДО NULL ВЕРНУТЬ */
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```